# ON clause in SQL join-does order matter?

Tags: mysql, join

Are these two same?

```
 - SELECT p.name,o.order_time FROM ORDERS o INNER JOIN PRODUCTS p on **o.product_id=p.id**;
 - SELECT p.name,o.order_time FROM ORDERS o INNER JOIN PRODUCTS p on **p.id=o.product_id**;
```

And are these two the same thing:

```
 - SELECT p.name,o.order_time FROM ORDERS o LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS p on **o.product_id=p.id;**
 - SELECT p.name,o.order_time FROM ORDERS o LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS p on **p.id=o.product_id;**
```

Comment: The change/swap  of columns in ON clause   produce the same  query ...  INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN may  produce different result

Comment: The order of the conditions in the ON clause doesn't matter. The queries per query pair you are showing are equal. If one query in a pair gives you different rows than the other, then this cannot be caused by the queries you are showing.

Comment: update your question and add  a  valid data sampke  ..  and your actual result

Comment: Please `select count(*)` instead in order to check the total result row count. Do these counts really differ?

Comment: Thanks folks,I just noticed I was looking at the query run number, no of rows is indeed the same on swapping order in ON clause.

Comment: `=` is commutative.

Comment: (Obviously,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Don't ask us to rewrite your textbook or the manual. Research & ask re being stuck in some presentation. Say what you expect & why, justifying per your reference. PS Ask 1 question per post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first 2 queries are exactly same in terms of performance and result. In addition to that, first 2 queries is same as below query,

> SELECT p.name,o.order_time FROM PRODUCTS p INNER JOIN ORDERS o   on **p.id=o.product_id**;

Which in turn is same as,

> SELECT p.name,o.order_time FROM PRODUCTS p INNER JOIN ORDERS o   on **o.product_id=p.id**;

**Note:** the order of inner join tables is swapped as well.

3rd and 4th are same as well in terms of performance and result. You can't swap the order of table here, unless dataset guarantees same result.

Based on the dataset, first 2 queries can yield same or different result than last 2 queries.

Reason is `=` is commutative, it means `a=b` is same as `b=a`. Extending it further, just `INNER JOIN` is also commutative.